# Why is this PHP/PDO sqlsrv query not returning results?

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I am trying to get results from a mssql database table using PDO in PHP, but it's not returning any results. However, I can count table rows - any advice?

```
  //this one working fine return 500 recrod in table
    $sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM Content";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $num_rows = $stmt->fetchColumn();

     //this one not returning anything 
    $sql = " SELECT c.*  FROM (
            SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID) AS RowID,*  FROM Content
            ) AS c 
        WHERE c.ID > :row_start AND c.ID <= :row_end
        ";
       $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
       $stmt->bindParam(':row_start', $row_start);
       $stmt->bindParam(':row_end', $row_end);
       $stmt->execute();

    $allsuck = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
     print_r($allsuck);
```

table info :

```
Array
(
    [0] => ID
    [1] => Title
    [2] => Fulldata
    [3] => description
    [4] => Catid
    [5] => language
    [6] => Created
    [7] => Userid
    [8] => MetaKey
    [9] => Thumbnail
    [10] => Thumbnail_desc
    [11] => Hits
    [12] => Active
    [13] => ModifiedDate
    [14] => ModifiedBy
    [15] => Fb_image
    [16] => important
    [17] => hashTags
)
```

Comment: An all-lower-case post featuring the word 'plz' from an 8.5K poster gets a downvote _immediately_. Urgh!

Comment: What is the point of the subquery like that?

Comment: @Mike i have table has over 16K record i am trying to use pagination system  this table is for test , counts working fine but display records return empty array

Comment: @halfer do u have solution for my question ?

Comment: @halfer OP has one answer with a score of 610, which equals about 6100 of the 8.5k...

Comment: @NinjaDevelopers I still don't see the point. Not that this necessarily answers your question, but just move the subquery to the main query because doing a subquery in this case doesn't do anything for you: `SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID) AS RowID,*  FROM Content WHERE Content.ID > :row_start AND Content.ID <= :row_end`

Comment: OP, it seems like Mike has an answer in hand for you. Please note the point I am making though - if you post in lower-case, or with text-speak, someone else has to later repair it. Editors will therefore be most grateful if you would write questions as carefully as possible.

Comment: @Mike agreed with you and its worked after i did what u said , post your answer dear

Comment: @NinjaDevelopers I posted the answer, however the thing is I don't know *why* that would solve your problem. I'm not really very knowledgeable of MS SQL, but are you sure there weren't any other sort of syntax errors anywhere?

Comment: @Mike for some reason its worked , i dunno why, i am just like you have low knowledge in MS SQL :)

Comment: Surely the outer where clause should be on `RowId` rather than `ID`?

Comment: @MarkSinkinson I bet you're right. OP, what sort of error reporting do you have on your PDO object? If you have it set to silent, try doing `$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` after your database connection and then execute your original query. It should throw an exception if there is a syntax error in your code. I have a feeling it's just silently continuing with the execution of your script instead of stopping it, which is why you *think* there are no rows being returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try moving the subquery to the main query because doing a subquery in this case doesn't do anything for you:

```sql
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID) AS RowID,* 
FROM Content 
WHERE Content.ID > :row_start 
AND Content.ID <= :row_end
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID) AS RowID,* 
  FROM Content 
) data
WHERE data.RowID > :row_start 
  AND data.RowID <= :row_end
```

You're filtering on the wrong column. `Id` will do nothing for you (otherwise why bother with the `ROW_NUMBER()`?). The filter should be on `RowId`

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER()`  better to use in pagination case

Comment: vote up , your solution is good too . this may help someone else

Comment: you should not do pagination on a id column. there may be gaps.

Comment: @Aツ I'm not doing pagination on the ID column. I'm doing pagination on the row_number()